# Validating AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, validation

I am working on a Java SE applicaiton that analyzes android applications.

Is there any schema/DTD that can be used to verify an AndroidManifest.xml?
If found namespace definitions like:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

But schemas.android.com does not resolve to an acutal host so no schema file there :-(

Note: I do **not** want to do the validation on Android as a platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the schemas for XML files on an Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605325/where-are-the-schemas-for-xml-files-on-an-android-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are no DTD/schemas for Android XML**, you have to relly on other tools which can do the validation, for example like Naresh explains.

Also see ["Where are the schemas for XML files on an Android project?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605325/where-are-the-schemas-for-xml-files-on-an-android-project)

Answer (score 2):

try aapt tool which comes with android-sdk. you can execute

aapt badge command to figure out details of android manifest xml from Android apk file

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll have a look at it.