# AndroidManifest.xml fails to run on device but compiles correctly

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I have built an Android app using `Unity3d`, written in `C#`. I'm trying to integrate Inneractive  (http://inner-active.com/) Ads, for it to work I need to change the `Android Manifest.xml`, I have absolutely no knowledge of this and can't find the answer via google.

The XML returns no errors in Unity when I compile my app, the app is pushed to the device but fails to run...I have attempted to merge 2 `AndroidManifest.Xml` to give my app access to both, I don't think I have done this correctly, as far as I can google it's not possible for me to simply have 2 `AndroidManifest.xml's`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InneractivePluginActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried validating your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Reference: [Validating AndroidManifest.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242929/validating-androidmanifest-xml-file).

I'd use the `aapt` tool and see what error you get while compiling the application. That should help you pinpoint the problem.

Also, it might help to go through the different tags and the properties in the Manifest and verify that they exist in the corresponding API version of Android as some properties for tags are added in newer versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, last day of work tomorrow for 2 weeks (hurrah!)so i'll give it a try then...will post back shortly!