# How is AndroidManifest.xml validated in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

How does android studio validate AndroidManifest.xml and any activity xml? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242929/validating-androidmanifest-xml-file) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605325/where-are-the-schemas-for-xml-files-on-an-android-project) and know that there isn't an actual schema for android manifest. But how does android studio or any tool that validates AndroidManifest.xml knows, what tags and elements are legal?

Comment: Recursively checking each tag, I imagine. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand that but it has to check against something to make sure that the tag or element is correct. In other words, if I change <category android:name ....> to<category android:namesss ....>, how does it know it is incorrect

Comment: I feel like I found the XML source once (maybe not, though). For the category tag, only the `name` attribute is valid. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything can be found on the https://android.googlesource.com.

The manifest model is not written as .xsd file. Instead it is written as a group of objects. The tree can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/)

If you start from [`Manifest`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Manifest.java) you can see, that it has the references to [`Application`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Application.java), [`List<UsesPermission>`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/UsesPermission.java), etc. The [`Application`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Application.java) has references to [`android:name`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Application.java#69) and [`android:label`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Application.java#73) and [`List<Activity>`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Activity.java) and so on.

A sample from `Activity` object:

```
@Attribute("name")
@Required
@Convert(PackageClassConverter.class)
@ExtendClass("android.app.Activity")
AndroidAttributeValue<PsiClass> getActivityClass();
```

As you can see this is the way, that Android Studio knows, that `activity` tag inside manifest must have a name. Two annotations are used:

```
@Attribute("name")
@Required
```

One of them is the name of .xml tag attribute, and the second one informs, that this attribute is required.

The names of tags, that can be used inside manifest can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/common/src/main/java/com/android/xml/AndroidManifest.java#43)

A helper class used by Android Studio to get manifest properties can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/b5197d2fb96e66e6fe50aa772eaadcbed6547cc1/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/model/ManifestInfo.java)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

> there isn't an actual schema for android manifest

I don't think this is correct. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/617716/1440565):

> The schemas don't exist as an xml file. Schemas are dependent upon what UI classes your program uses.

While there isn't a schema defined directly in an XML file, the valid tags and attributes can be defined elsewhere, such as in the Java code which parses and inflates an XML layout.

Comment: So do you mean that android studio looks into classes and determine the elements?

Comment: @Kode I mean that Android Studio has code which opens the XML files and looks at it directly. Most likely this is implemented with Java classes, but it's not "looking into classes". Rather it's looking into the XML files that it parses.

Comment: I see what you are saying but are you sure about this or is it an educated guess?

Comment: This is an educated guess.