# insert a new line and some text after matching some text c#

Tags: c#

i have a txt file that contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" blablabla ..etc>
  <uses-permission ~~~~~~ ..etc>
  <application ~~~some of words i dont know it and changes from file to another file~~~ >
  </application>
</manifest>
```

i need to add "Hello World" in new line at a specific position and the final file will be look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" blablabla ..etc>
  <uses-permission ~~~~~~ ..etc>
Hello World
  <application ~~~some of words i dont know it and changes from file to another file~~~ >
Hello World
  </application>
</manifest>
```

pls, how can i do this in c# ? and i dont know some words in the line that i will add "Hello World" After it so i need to detect the line first like "<application " in line 195 then add a new line after 195 it will be 196 then add the words "Hello World"

Comment: or deserialize / serialize the XML file to a safer aproach

Comment: @Dai u mean Regex : Regular Expression ? can u help me with code cuz i am noob

Comment: @user16535021 So that I can better tailor a response for you, what is your level of computer-science or software-engineering education?

Comment: ...... @Dai 404

Comment: Please post your entire source text / XML file _without any changes_ being made to it. Is it a valid (structurally correct) XML file or is it a [_tag-soup_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup) file?

Comment: @Dai any AndroidManifest.XML file i just need to add some specific permissions and some services

Comment: @Dai but permissions after permissions and services in the line after  "<application ...etc>"

Comment: @user16535021 Are you wanting to add `<uses-permission>` elements or `<permission>` elements?

Comment: @Dai for permissions `<uses-permission>` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to manipulate an Android app manifest XML file.

  - [The format is documented on the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro). Unfortunately [there doesn't seem to be an XSD Schema available for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441410/how-is-androidmanifest-xml-validated-in-android-studio), but for trivial changes that won't be necessary.
- Use the *right tool for the right job*.

  - **Do not process XML documents as text**:

    - I can tell from your initial post that this is what you were thinking of:

      > After it so I need to detect the line first like "`<application` in line 195 then add a new line after 195 it will be 196 then add the words `"Hello World"`
      > The problem is, XML does not care about line-numbers: two semantically identical XML documents can have wildly different distributions of line-breaks at the most awkward of places.
    - Remember: XML documents are not plain text files.
    - XML documents (and related, such as SGML and HTML)'s elements [cannot be reliably parsed and extracted with regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).
    - This is because [XML's grammar is a context-free grammar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722751/is-well-formed-xml-context-sensitive-grammar), which [places it above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) [regular-grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) [in the Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) (ergo, you cannot use a regular-expression, Q.E.D.).
  - This means you should use a XML-procesing library instead. Fortunately .NET has *at least 2* of them:

    - `System.Xml` - this is the older XML library from .NET Framework 1.x days (2000-2002). It is modelled on an early standard for the W3C DOM and is very hard to use.
    - `System.Xml.Linq` (aka "*Linq to XML"*) - this is a modern (relatively speaking) library that came out in .NET Framework 3.5 (at the same time as Linq and all manner of *nice things* that we still enjoy today). The API design is very different, but also far more succinct and expressive compared to `System.Xml`. I note that it is designed primarily for querying XML instead of mutating XML, but for our purposes it's fine.

      - Read this first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/add-elements-attributes-nodes-xml-tree

---

While (generally speaking), the order of elements in Android manifest files [does not matter, there are 2 documented exceptions where *order does matter*, and unfortunately for us the 2nd exception applies to us](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#filec):

1. An `<activity-alias>` element must follow the `<activity>` for which it is an alias.
2. The `<application>` element must be the last element inside the `<manifest>` element.

So the bird's eye view is:

1. Load the Android app manifest XML file into an `XDocument` object.
2. To add [a new `<uses-permission>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element) or [a new `<permission>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element), you need to add as an immediate child of the root `<manifest>` element, but located *before* the `<application>` element.
3. To add [a new `<service>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element) you append it to `<application>` as a new immediate-child element.

---

Like so:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    public static Int32 Main( String[] args )
    {
        const String FILE_NAME = "MyManifest.xml";
        
        if( !File.Exists( FILE_NAME ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Couldn't find \"" + FILE_NAME + "\"." );
            return 1;
        }

        // Load the XML from disk:
        String manifestXmlText = File.ReadAllText( FILE_NAME  );
        
        // Parse it into an an XDocument:
        XDocument manifestXmlDocument = XDocument.Parse( manifestXmlText );
        
        // Add the new elements:
        AddElementsToAndroidManifest( manifestXmlDocument );

        // Then save the updated XML document back to disk, overwriting the original file:
        using( FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite( FILE_NAME ) )
        {
            manifestXmlDocument.Save( fs );
        }

        return 0;
    }
    
    private static void AddElementsToAndroidManifest( XDocument manifestXmlDocument )
    {
        XElement   manifestEl    = manifestXmlDocument.Root                                         ?? throw new InvalidOperationException( "Couldn't find root <manifest> element." ) ;
        XElement   applicationEl = manifestXmlDocument.Descendants("application").SingleOrDefault() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException( "Couldn't find <application> element." ); // Get the <application> element.
        XNamespace androidNS     = manifestEl.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(prefix: "android")               ?? throw new InvalidOperationException( "Couldn't find xmlns:android" );; // "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        {
            // <uses-permission>'s attributes use XML namespaces, so this complicates things:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985974/xelement-namespaces-how-to
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/namespaces-overview
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874422/how-to-set-the-default-xml-namespace-for-an-xdocument
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338517/how-can-i-write-xml-with-a-namespace-and-prefix-with-xelement

            XElement newUsesPermissionEl = new XElement( "uses-permission",
                new XAttribute( androidNS + "name"         , "bar"), 
                new XAttribute( androidNS + "maxSdkVersion", "123")
            );

            applicationEl.AddBeforeSelf( newUsesPermissionEl ); // Add the new <uses-permission> element as a preceding sibling of <application>.
        }

        {
            // <service>:

            XElement newServiceEl = new XElement( "service",
                new XAttribute( androidNS + "description", "Some day, some day, Some day, Dominion; Some day, some day, Some say prayers; I say mine"), 
                new XAttribute( androidNS + "name"       , "Dominion service"),
                new XAttribute( androidNS + "label"      , "Andrew Eldritch fanclub <3"),
            );

            applicationEl.Add( newServiceEl ); // Add the new <service> element as an immediately child of <application>.
        }
    }
}
```

---

So given [the official example Manifest XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#example) as input (in `MyManifest.xml`)...:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.myapp">
  <!-- Beware that these values are overridden by the build.gradle file -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- This name is resolved to com.example.myapp.MainActivity
             based upon the package attribute -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

...I get this output:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.myapp">
  <!-- Beware that these values are overridden by the build.gradle file -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <uses-permission android:name="bar" android:maxSdkVersion="123" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- This name is resolved to com.example.myapp.MainActivity
             based upon the package attribute -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <service android:description="Some day, some day, Some day, Dominion; Some day, some day, Some say prayers; I say mine" android:name="Dominion service" android:label="Andrew Eldritch fanclub &lt;3" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see, the `<service>` and `<uses-permission>` elements have been inserted in their correct places.

Comment: @user16535021 In my best Commissioner Gordon voice: _It's what you want, but is it what you deserve?_

Comment: bro i use .NET Framework then you should to use FileStream because System.IO not provides File.ReadAllTextAsync method.

Comment: @user16535021 You didn't mention that in your posting. But I'm sure you're able to use the non-async methods just fine.

Comment: @Dia can you fix `GetNamespaceOfPrefix`  Error : XDocument does not contain a definition for 'GetNamespaceOfPrefix' and no accessible  extension method ....

Comment: @user16535021 My mistake. Please try my updated code.

Comment: @Dia You are so professional, with no errors, thank you very much.

Comment: @user16535021 I am a _professional_ StackOverflow timewaster

Comment: @Dia bro if you can help , `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487221/find-a-words-in-text-file-then-skip-two-lines-then-add-a-new-line-with-words-c-s`

Comment: @user16535021 Why, though?