# Find a words in text file then skip two lines then add a new line with words c#

Tags: c#

i have a text file that contain texts like this

```
.end method

.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.locals 7

.line 83
```

i need to find ".method public onCreate" then skip the line after it and add "Hello World" in a new line

the text file will be like this

```
.end method

.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.locals 7
Hello World
.line 83
```

can any one help me with code in c# ?

this is my code :

```
string pubmethod = ".method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V";

var x = File.ReadAllLines(mclass2);

var y = x.Where(w => w.Contains(pubmethod));

foreach (var item in y)
{
    // skip line and add  "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: what have you tried yourself?  Where/Why did that attempt fail?

Comment: i can check if the file contain this ".method public onCreate" or not but i cant add words after lines

Comment: @user17766888 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: i edited the question, now how can i skip line and add "Hello World" ?

Comment: A text file is conceptually a stream of bytes. But, in reality, it's a file on disk, where each byte in the file matches a physical byte on the disk. You can't open a file, read a bit, and then add a line to the middle of the file. You need to read from one file and write to another. One you are satisfied that the read/write operations are complete, delete the orignal file and rename the new one to match

Comment: after i find the line can i copy all text above the line in new txt file and also the text down to a  new second txt file and edit the third line in the second new txt file then gather all the texts in one text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MyLines(string fileName) {
  int state = 1;

  foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(fileName)) 
    if (state == 1) {
      if (line == ".method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V")
        state = 2;

      yield return line;
    }
    else if (state == 2) {
      yield return "Hello World";

      state = 3;
    } 
    else
      yield return line;
}
```

Possible usage:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

var mclass2 = @"c:\MyFile.txt";

...

string[] lines = MyLines("mclass2").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a variable which keeps track of a match (i.e. `found`).

I decided to update that variable with the value 2, and decrement it each line.

When the value equals 0, I do output "Hello World". (after this the value of `found` will keep decrementing...)

```
            string pubmethod = ".method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V";
            var x = File.ReadAllLines(mclass2);
            //var y = x.Where(w => w.Contains(pubmethod));
            int found = 0;
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                if (item.Contains(pubmethod)) found = 2;
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                found--;
                if (found==0) Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            }
```